# Lighttpd + Django configuration - "waiting for connection"

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, lighttpd

I would like to configure Lighttpd with Django to show at localhost:3033 basic "hello-world" Django website (created by `$ django-admin startproject hellodjango`). I've followed [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/), but I can't make my website work. After going to localhost:3033 nothing happens and the only thing I see is the message" waiting for conncetion".

My **lighttpd.config**

```
server.groupname            = "www-data"

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html",
                                "index.htm", "default.htm",
                               " index.lighttpd.html" )

url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl"

dir-listing.encoding        = "utf-8"
server.dir-listing          = "enable"

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/x-javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"


# My configuration
$HTTP["host"] == "www.hellodjango.com" {

    server.document-root = "/home/krris/programowanie/django/hellodjango"
    server.errorlog = "/home/krris/programowanie/django/hellodjango/logs/error.log"
    accesslog.filename = "/home/krris/programowanie/django/hellodjango/logs/access.log"
    fastcgi.server = (
        "/hellodjango.fcgi" => (
            "main" => (
                # Use host / port instead of socket for TCP fastcgi
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => 3033,
                # "socket" => "/home/krris/hellodjango.sock",
                "check-local" => "disable",
            )
        ),
    )
    alias.url = (
        "/media/" => "/home/krris/programowanie/django/hellodjango/media/",
    )

    url.rewrite-once = (
        "^(/media.*)$" => "$1",
        "^/favicon\.ico$" => "/media/favicon.ico",
        "^(/.*)$" => "/hellodjango.fcgi$1",
    )
}
```

**hellodjango.fcgi**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "..")

# Switch to the directory of your project. (Optional.)
os.chdir("/home/krris/programowanie/django/hellodjango")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "hellodjango.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="prefork", daemonize="true", host="127.0.0.1", port="3033")
```

I've also added this line to **settings.py**:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = ""
```

I run my application using a command:

```
$ ./manage.py runfcgi method=prefork host=127.0.0.1 port=3033
```

**error.log:**

```
2013-03-19 11:27:10: (log.c.166) server started 
2013-03-19 11:27:16: (server.c.1396) [note] graceful shutdown started 
2013-03-19 11:27:16: (log.c.166) server started 
2013-03-19 11:27:16: (server.c.1512) server stopped by UID = 0 PID = 8093
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is stopped for some reason. A possible way to debug is set daemonize="false" here:

runfastcgi(method="prefork", daemonize="true", host="127.0.0.1", port="3033")

This may help you see what is happening and why your server shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried doing what you've just done. 
The other thing I found to make this work (I think) is to ensure:

- .fcgi file has executable rights for everyone.
- log folder has to have rights as well.

What I see though is just a file list view of the project folder. 
Is this what you get? 
Also it does not work via the www.helloDjango.com url for me.

Let me know if you get the same results please.
I am also finding that to get a basic hello world page up is really difficult and confusing.